# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't see specific Wifi connection

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

Using Ubuntu (actually Xubuntu but probably no difference for this) 20.04 I have a problem connecting to my new (work) wifi network. I need to stress that connecting to most Wifi is just fine eg my home network has no problems and I can go into various cafes and hotels etc and connect with no problem. But not this one. I have just started working here and I really need to connect to their WiFi. But I can't.

I can connect to this work Wifi from my Android phone no problem. My colleagues can connect from their MACs no problem. It's just me (which is awkward). First, when I try to connect the WiFi network doesn't show up in the list. This is the first danger sign. To try and overcome that I created a manual entry, gave it a valid password and told it to use Mode: Client, Band: Automatic, Channel: default. I set the security to WPA & WPA2 Personal. That created a file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. That connected but used Hotspot as its mode (huh?) which gives me no real network connectivity. After editing it a bit to make it look like my home wifi w different names I got this:

```
[connection]
id=Sinclair House 6
uuid=4c05a113-015e-414e-84b1-f655e02e04b6
type=wifi
autoconnect=false
interface-name=wlp7s0
permissions=

[wifi]
hidden=false
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=client
ssid='Sinclair House'

[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=REDACTED

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto

[proxy]
```

But this too ends up connecting in hotspot mode. It is also still hidden. I'm not completely sure that editing the file is all I have to do to change the connection, so I'm keen to hear advice on that. There used to be a 'forget' option but it has been discontinued. It would be quite useful just now.
I have tried changing the mode from client to infrastructure but no change to behaviour.
I think the real problem is why my Ubuntu does not see the Wifi in the first place. I have no access to the modem, can't fiddle w settings etc, but obviously I can change my own machine.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: added log output (extract) as requested `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`

```
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.1879] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.1889] device (wlp7s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.1892] device (wlp7s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Sinclair House 3' has security, but secrets are required.
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.1892] device (wlp7s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.1923] device (wlp7s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.1930] device (wlp7s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.1935] device (wlp7s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Sinclair House 3' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.1939] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Sinclair House'
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.1940] Config: added 'mode' value '1'
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.1942] Config: added 'frequency' value '2412'
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.1944] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.1945] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.1946] Config: added 'proto' value 'RSN'
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.1947] Config: added 'pairwise' value 'CCMP'
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.1947] Config: added 'group' value 'CCMP'
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.2118] device (wlp7s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> associating
Apr 12 09:45:31 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713531.2118] device (p2p-dev-wlp7s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> associating
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.2600] device (wlp7s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.2601] device (wlp7s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "Sinclair House"
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.2601] device (p2p-dev-wlp7s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> completed
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.2654] device (wlp7s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.3056] Executing: /usr/sbin/iptables --table filter --insert INPUT --in-interface wlp7s0 --protocol tcp --destination-port 53 --jump ACCEPT
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.3080] Executing: /usr/sbin/iptables --table filter --insert INPUT --in-interface wlp7s0 --protocol udp --destination-port 53 --jump ACCEPT
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.3101] Executing: /usr/sbin/iptables --table filter --insert INPUT --in-interface wlp7s0 --protocol tcp --destination-port 67 --jump ACCEPT
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.3122] Executing: /usr/sbin/iptables --table filter --insert INPUT --in-interface wlp7s0 --protocol udp --destination-port 67 --jump ACCEPT
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.3151] Executing: /usr/sbin/iptables --table filter --insert FORWARD --in-interface wlp7s0 --jump REJECT
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.3177] Executing: /usr/sbin/iptables --table filter --insert FORWARD --out-interface wlp7s0 --jump REJECT
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.3197] Executing: /usr/sbin/iptables --table filter --insert FORWARD --in-interface wlp7s0 --out-interface wlp7s0 --jump ACCEPT
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.3223] Executing: /usr/sbin/iptables --table filter --insert FORWARD --source 10.42.0.0/255.255.255.0 --in-interface wlp7s0 --jump ACCEPT
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.3251] Executing: /usr/sbin/iptables --table filter --insert FORWARD --destination 10.42.0.0/255.255.255.0 --out-interface wlp7s0 --match state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED --jump ACCEPT
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.3274] Executing: /usr/sbin/iptables --table nat --insert POSTROUTING --source 10.42.0.0/255.255.255.0 ! --destination 10.42.0.0/255.255.255.0 --jump MASQUERADE
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.3299] dnsmasq-manager: starting dnsmasq...
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.3313] device (wlp7s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict dnsmasq[43038]: started, version 2.80 cachesize 150
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict dnsmasq[43038]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth nettlehash DNSSEC loop-detect inotify dumpfile
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict dnsmasq[43038]: chown of PID file /run/nm-dnsmasq-wlp7s0.pid failed: Operation not permitted
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict dnsmasq-dhcp[43038]: DHCP, IP range 10.42.0.10 -- 10.42.0.254, lease time 1h
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict dnsmasq[43038]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict dnsmasq[43038]: using nameserver 127.0.0.53#53
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict dnsmasq[43038]: cleared cache
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.3463] device (wlp7s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.3467] device (wlp7s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict NetworkManager[1065]: <info>  [1649713538.3471] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
```

The most suspicious thing to me in this is the line:

```
Apr 12 09:45:38 benedict dnsmasq[43038]: chown of PID file /run/nm-dnsmasq-wlp7s0.pid failed: Operation not permitted
```

(benedict is my machine name)
I compared it to the logs of when I connect through my phone hotspot and there's a fair difference but I don't see any actual errors in the above except for that one. I don't see anything that explicitly switches it to hotspot, but that is what it ends up with.

Comment: Look at the network logs: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Vary the number after `-b` to select earlier boots (-1 previous, -2 the one before that, ...)

Comment: @waltinator Thanks for the response. I have added an extract from the log that covers bringing up the problem connection.